# Cypress e2e: unable to test multi-domain using cy.origin()?

Tags: cypress, cross-domain

I am learning cy.origin concept and found below snippet from internet said it's working good. I am getting an error as unable to find element: #login_field. I've also set true chromeWebSecurity & experimentalSessionAndOrigin but still error. Kindly help to solve.

```js
describe('Test login to Netlify using Github', () => {
    it("should login to netlify with github", () => {
     // visit netlify
     cy.visit("https://www.netlify.com/");
     cy.get("#cta-mainNav-login").click({ force: true });
     cy.wait(5000)
     cy.contains("Log in").click({ force: true });
     cy.contains("GitHub").click({ force: true });
 
     // click on 'login with Github' button
     cy.origin("https://github.com", () => {
       cy.get('#login_field').type("*****@gmail.com");
       cy.get("#password").type("********");
       cy.get("input").contains("Sign in").click();
     });
 
     // should login to netlify and open dashboard
     cy.url().should("contain", "https://app.netlify.com/");
   });
 });
```

Comment: I'm not getting that error - do you need a longer timeout? `cy.get('#login_field', {timeout:20000})`

Comment: I get another button to click before redirect back to Netlify - contains "Authorize netlify". It's still on github domain, so clicking it should be inside the `cy.origin()`.

Comment: I updated Cypress to V10 then it's working fine now. I learnt a new thing about Cypress today as this should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add to following config to the `cypress.config.xx` file?

```
experimentalOriginDependencies: true,
```